# I am trying to bet with CAKE, previously it was BNB, but I am getting "invalid BigNumber value" error

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain

I am trying to bet with CAKE, previously it was BNB.

```js
//Bet UP
const betUp = async (amount, epoch) => {
  try {
    const tx = await predictionContract.betBull(epoch, {
      value: parseEther(amount.toFixed(18).toString()),
    });
    await tx.wait();
    console.log( Successful bet of ${amount} CAKE to UP );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Transaction Error", error);
    GLOBAL_CONFIG.WAITING_TIME = reduceWaitingTimeByTwoBlocks(
      GLOBAL_CONFIG.WAITING_TIME
    );
  }
};

//Bet DOWN
const betDown = async (amount, epoch) => {
  try {
    const tx = await predictionContract.betBear(epoch, {
      value: parseEther(amount.toFixed(18).toString()),
    });
    await tx.wait();
    console.log( Successful bet of ${amount} CAKE to DOWN );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Transaction Error", error);
    GLOBAL_CONFIG.WAITING_TIME = reduceWaitingTimeByTwoBlocks(
      GLOBAL_CONFIG.WAITING_TIME
    );
  }
};
```

The error I get is

```
reason: 'invalid BigNumber value',
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'value',
value: {
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0838b02dc43a0752', _isBigNumber: true }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say what's your problem without sharing `parseEther()` function. Please include it in your question.

Comment: Ok, I think the parseEther() is sending native token of the network which is BNB, how would you change that to send token instead of BNB to the predictioncontract?

Comment: I see. Which contract address are you using currently for `predictionContract`?

Comment: It's smart contract address (0x0E3A8078EDD2021dadcdE733C6b4a86E51EE8f07) where the token need to be send, thats the predictionContract its using.

Comment: Seems like a correct address. Can you share that `parseEther()` function to see what's going on there? And what is the `amount` you're setting? I believe that the problem you have lies somewhere in `parseEther(amount.toFixed(18).toString())`.

Comment: amount is being calculated every rounds. The problem is the amount is being thought to be BNB, I don't know how to make it CAKE.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CAKE token, you should handle both contracts (CAKE contract and "prediction" contract) and give approval to spend the tokens on your behalf.

I hope this code snippet will help you to figure out how to handle it (replace relevant values as needed):

```js
const myAddress = 'YOUR_ADDRESS';

const cakeAddress = '0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82';  // https://bscscan.com/token/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82
const cakeAbi = 'USE_CAKE_CONTRACT_ABI_HERE';
const cakeContract = new Contract(cakeAddress, cakeAbi, provider.getSigner());
const cakeBalance = await cakeContract.balanceOf(myAddress);
const amountToBet = 'AMOUNT_TO_BET';

const predictionAddress = '0x0E3A8078EDD2021dadcdE733C6b4a86E51EE8f07';  // as per https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/products/prediction/
const predictionAbi = 'USE_PREDITION_CONTRACT_ABI_HERE';
const predictionContract = new Contract(predictionAddress, predictionAbi, provider.getSigner());
const currentEpoch = await predictionContract.currentEpoch();

// approve CAKE usage, modify cakeBalance if needed
await cakeContract.approve(predictionAddress, cakeBalance);
const tx = await predictionContract.betBull(currentEpoch, amountToBet);
```